# Как при помощи flex расположить следующие идущие слева и справа на одной строке, а верхний на одной

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
чтобы классы true был слева, а false справа на одной строке, 
а класс tittle как и есть на одной строке и по контенту,
обвернуть не выход

```css
.wrapper{
  
display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}

.wrapper .title{
  display: flex;
  flex:1 100%;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.wrapper .true{
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: content;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='title'><div class='name'>заголовок</div><button class='prop'>свойства</button></div>
<button class='true'>true</button>
<button class='false'>false</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно проста обернуть два кнопки в один родитель `.buttons` и дать им

`display:flex ,justify-content:space-between`

```css
.wrapper{
  
display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}

.wrapper .title{
  display: flex;
  flex:1 100%;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.wrapper .true{
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: content;
}
.buttons {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='title'><div class='name'>заголовок</div><button class='prop'>свойства</button></div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class='true'>true</button>
  <button class='false'>false</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: я знаю что такой вариант поможет, но у меня нету возможности обвернуть(

Comment: @recile тогда при помощи `flex` вы такое не сделаете